# Searching through an entire series of synsets (from NLTK) in Python NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

*Original question:*

*The polysemy of a word is the number of senses it has. Using WordNet, we can
determine that the noun dog has seven senses with len(wn.synsets('dog', 'n')).
Compute the average polysemy of nouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs according
to WordNet.*

From what I gathered from the question, I was to use a built in polysemy method in NLTK with WordNet to find out the number of senses something has.

More importantly, I am trying to use all of the available synsets available and loop them through,
and placing all of the values returned into a set.
After this, I would have intended to add the total number of all the synsets in the set(filled with integers) that was newly created to receive a sum.
After I obtain this sum, I would have divided the total number of entries to receive the average.

My biggest question is... how would I go about looping through **all** of the synsets available as well as the nouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs?

- After researching through various websites, I've found that for "wn.all_synsets('n')" will return all of the possible noun synsets.

However the type it returns is a "generator", how would I go about using loops to iterate through a "generator" type?

.>>>allsynsets = wn.all_synsets('n')

.>>> allsynsets

<.generator object all_synsets at 0x04359F30>

.>>> type(allsynsets)

<.type 'generator'>

I hope I've provided enough information to allow anyone to find an answer to this problem.
I do not have source code, aside from imports and tests to understand the generator type for this problem.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either of these methods should work

```
list = [x for x in wx.all_synsets('n')]
```

or

```
for x in wx.all_synsets('n'):
    print x
```

[edit] this talks more about generators (among many other sources on the web)
http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/NBN/generators.html

Comment: Dont use the name `list` for variables as you lose access to the function `list()`. Speaking of the function `list()`, if you want all the items in a generator as a list you can just call `list(wx.all_synsets('n'))`.

Comment: yes this is true ... sorry was just giving an example and didn't think about var names :P  but yeah don't name the actual variable list and the  list(<generator>) is a better way to convert it to a list i guess also.

Comment: Alright thank you,
I was trying something new in Python, and was genuinely stuck,
and felt that I've exhausted every resource possible (well, that I knew of).
Thank you again!